# nodeJS: Command not found when installed a library from source code instead of npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install nodeJS library by downloading the source code instead of npm library, because I want to use some new features that are not present in the official library yet but I am getting command not found error.

I am trying install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/bids-validator

I was able to use `npm install -g bids-validator` and it is installing the package and I am able to use it.

But If download source code from GitHub https://github.com/bids-standard/bids-validator and go to the the folder and use `npm install`, I didn't get any installation errors but I am getting following error

```
'bids-validator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `npm install` only installs the dependencies (and dev dependencies) of the project. It doesn't do any linking or anything.

Comment: Then how do I install from local source code and use that command?

Comment: [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link/)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are trying to run 'bids-validator' inside the directory of that library?  That's not how this works. The library would have a executable file somewhere that needs to be ran with the "execute" permission (assuming unix-like os). You will be able to find which file it is by looking for a "bin" property in one of the package.json files.

Comment: @ncpa0cpl I am trying install from that directory so that I can use that 'bids-validator' command. Is that possible?

Comment: Since this is a npm package it probably does not have a "installer", if you want to have it available to use globally you can either install it via npm with a `-g` flag (https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally) or find that executable file and add it location to your local PATH (https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7)